# Problem with of alignment with 4 tikzpictures in a figure environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, floats, minipage, textwidth

Good afternoon,

I just to need to shift all of these for graphs a little bit more to the left, and spacing (vertically) the former two with respect to the latter. I tried with `\hspace`, but it produces the following:[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{figure}
\hspace{-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {$\text{A\&D}/100k$},
ylabel = {$gp$},
xmin = 0,
ymin = 0,
xmax = 325,
ymax = 325,
xtick={0,80},
ytick={160+20/3,240+20/3},
title = {Tourists, Peak},
]
\addplot[
domain = 0:240,
samples = 190,
thick,
]
{240 + 20/3 - x};
\draw [dotted] (0,160+20/3) -- (80,160+20/3) -- (80,0);
\draw[pattern= north east lines,pattern color = green] (0,160+20/3) -- (0,240+20/3)-- (80,160+20/3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {$\text{A\&D}/100k$},
ylabel = {$gp$},
xmin = 0,
ymin = 0,
xmax = 325,
ymax = 325,
xtick={0,20},
ytick={120+10/3,180+10/3},
title = {Tourists, Off-Peak},
]
\addplot[
domain = 0:300,
samples = 190,
thick,
]
{180 + 10/3 - 3*x};
\draw [dotted] (0,120+10/3) -- (20,120+10/3) -- (20,0);
\draw[pattern= north east lines,pattern color = green] (0,120+10/3) -- (0,180+10/3)-- (20,120+10/3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {$\text{A\&D} / 100k$},
ylabel = {$gp$},
xmin = 0,
ymin = 0,
xmax = 60,
ymax = 730,
xtick={0,20},
ytick={40+20/3,160+20/3,560+20/3},
title = {Locals, Peak},
]
\addplot[
domain = 0:75,
samples = 190,
thick,
]
{560 + 20/3 - 20*x};
\draw [dotted] (0,160+20/3) -- (20,160+20/3) -- (20,0);
\draw [dotted] (0,40+20/3) -- (26, 40 + 20/3) -- (26,0);
\draw [pattern = north east lines, pattern color = green](0, 40 + 20/3) -- (0,560 + 20/3) -- (20, 160 + 20/3) -- (20, 40 + 20/3);
\draw [pattern = north east lines, pattern color = red](20, 40 + 20/3) -- (20, 160 + 20/3) -- (26,40 + 20/3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
axis lines = left,
xlabel = {$\text{A\&D} / 100k$},
ylabel = {$gp$},
xmin = 0,
ymin = 0,
xmax = 60,
ymax = 730,
xtick={0,30},
ytick={30+10/3,120+10/3,420+10/3},
title = {Locals, Off-Peak},
]
\addplot[
domain = 0:75,
samples = 190,
thick,
]
{420 + 10/3 - 10*x};
\draw [dotted] (0,120+10/3) -- (30,120+20/3) -- (30,0);
\draw [dotted] (0,30+10/3) -- (39, 30 + 10/3) -- (39,0);
\draw [pattern = north east lines, pattern color = green](0, 30 + 10/3) -- (0,420 + 10/3) -- (30, 120 + 10/3) -- (30, 30 + 10/3);
\draw [pattern = north east lines, pattern color = red](30, 30 + 10/3) -- (30, 120 + 10/3) -- (39,30 + 10/3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Check out group plots starting on page 454 of the pgfplots manual.

Comment: Solved simply using ```\subfigure```.